# Data transfer via Serial TX and RX ports in Raspberry PI 3

Tags: linux, python-3.x, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I am quite new in serial connection in Linux and raspberry pi3 . and I am trying to send numbers to RoboClaw Motor Driver and received feedback values from it  through Serial ports (Tx,Rx).
In below there are list of available ports,I have tried many ways, but still I do not know that I need to disable the  Console or no. I am using Python for coding.

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1184 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=624 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa22082 bcm2709.serial=0x8cc60317 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:C6:03:17 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles

***[    0.000496] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.296892] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.296949] 3f215040.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x3f215040 (irq = 59, base_baud = 31250000) is a 16550
[    0.297476] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.784136] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2***
[    3.275091] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyS0.device...
[    3.340413] systemd[1]: Starting system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    3.340681] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
```

Is there any advice that how I can setup and run data transmision via these ports?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching - there is lots of information out there if you google for, let's say _raspberry pi 3 serial uart_

Comment: I read a lot, and all of them telling a different method and some time quite different. I am looking for solution that have been done recently and work to find out what is wrong with my works.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently gone through this process. 
Here are some resources that helped me, and that I will basically be sourcing my answer from.

[rpi pinout](https://pinout.xyz)

[Configuring The GPIO Serial Port On Raspbian Jessie Including Pi 3](https://spellfoundry.com/2016/05/29/configuring-gpio-serial-port-raspbian-jessie-including-pi-3/)

If bluetooth is not in use, I would recommend following the instructions to use AMA0 instead (some people have reported clock speed/transmission issues on ttyS0)

I also used IonMotion studio to make sure that the address, comm mode, are properly set on the roboclaw's.